# failed to convert byte array into image in some certain browser

Tags: c#, asp.net

i am using Visual studio 2010 with .Net 3.5 framework

my code work fine in my windows 8, IE 9

however it doesnt work in windows xp , IE7, i have no idea what is exactly happen

```
Byte[] byImg = ((byte[])dr["logo"]);
var vBase64String = Convert.ToBase64String(byImg);
logo.ImageUrl = string.Format("data:image/gif;base64,{0}", vBase64String);
```

is there any support issue?

Comment: What is broken?  Is there an exception?

Comment: no exception, somehow IE7 cant display the picture ~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE7 does [not support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc848897%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) `data:` protocol for images. It is implemented in IE8 and above.

If you need to support IE7 - server separate image files instead.

Comment: @Alexi, is that other way to form a picture from byte[] to image without using data: protocol ?

Comment: No... You need to generate Url (like "/generatedimages/imagehandler.ashx?id=image1234") and implement handler (like "ashx" file if using WebForms) that will serve bytes for that image. Search for something like "C# asp.Net render image" to find more info like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/186062/can-an-asp-net-mvc-controller-return-an-image (also this one for MVC)

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12178495/an-efficient-way-to-base64-encode-a-byte-array):

```
string imageDataParsed = imageData.Substring( imageData.IndexOf( ',' ) + 1 );
byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String( imageDataParsed );
using ( var imageStream = new MemoryStream( imageBytes, false ) )
{
   Bitmap image = new Bitmap( imageStream );
}
```

Comment: hi dude, i will try it at night, will mark you as answer if it really help =)